# Storing Structs in a Generic Array

Tags: swift, generics

I’m trying to create a `struct` which acts as a storage for the results being returned from a web API. This API returns different `JSON` results which are modeled as a set of `struct`s.

These results need to be stored in an array inside of a storage `class` which will need to be generic as it should be able to store arrays of any of the types returned. I’m struggling, however, with adding generic data to an array… and this is where you guys might come in.

This is the storage `class`:

```
class FooStorage<F: Fooable> {
    private var storage: [F] = []
    
    func add<F: Fooable>(_ someFoo: F) {
        storage.append(someFoo)
    }
}
```

These are two sample `structs` modeling what the API mentioned will return:

```
struct FooA: Fooable, Decodable {
    var foo: String
}

struct FooB: Fooable, Decodable {
    var foo: String
    var bar: String
}
```

And finally, this is the protocol I created in order to specify that all of these `structs` are results of the same API:

```
protocol Fooable {}
```

The compiler error I get is this:

> No exact matches in call to instance method append

And it is thrown on the `storage.append(_:)` method of the `FooStorage` class. Tried to add `Equatable` and `Hashable` conformance to the `FooX` protocols but to no avail. Seems I need some enlightenment here… thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your add function, remove the generic part & let it use the `class` generic:

```
class FooStorage<F: Fooable> {
    private var storage: [F] = []
    
    func add(_ someFoo: F) {
        storage.append(someFoo)
    }
}
```

Comment: That simple!? Obviously I didn’t see the wood for the trees… Thanks a lot, @NoeOnJupiter!